# -U equivalent to Maven ant task "artifact:dependencies"

Tags: maven, ant

Maven's -U argument forces Maven to go out and seek & download the latest snapshots.  I'm in a position where I'm using the Maven ant tasks and I'm looking for the equivalent parameter for the ant task "artifact:dependencies"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answer is: there is no way.

There is a workaround, however: ~/.m2/settings.xml

Create a profile and add:

```
  <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
```

to the description of the repository.  In our case, we use Artifactory to proxy other repos (as well as hold our internal projects) so I could accomplish forcing the "-U" to work by having settings.xml.  Maven's Ant tasks will take properties/profiles/repos/etc defined in settings.xml just like it would if being called from maven + pom project.

Example excerpt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>releases</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://MY_ARTIFACTORY_INSTALL:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://MY_ARTIFACTORY_INSTALL:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <id>myProfile</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>myProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant “artifact:dependencies” can have a remoteRepository and releases nested elements. Thus, you can specify updatePolicy using releases element attribute. See https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/reference.html#remoteRepository for more information.

```
<artifact:dependencies ...>
     <remoteRepository id="mySuperDuperNexusRepo"
         url="http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/">
             <releases updatePolicy="always"/>
     </remoteRepository>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

This might work.